# Quicksort implementation isn't returning expected result

Tags: java, quicksort

I've been trying to write up a quicksort algorithm in Java, but it's not working correctly. I've compared the code with several other implementations online and I honestly can't figure out what the issue is.

```
public class Quicksort {
public void sort(int[] list){
    sort(list, 0, list.length - 1);
}

private void sort(int[] list, int li, int hi){
    if (li < hi){
        int pi = partition(list, li, hi);
        sort(list, li, pi - 1);
        sort(list, pi + 1, hi);
    }
}

private int partition(int[] list, int li, int hi){
    int pivot = list[hi];

    int i = (li - 1);
    
    for (int j = li; j <= hi; j++){
        if (list[j] < pivot){
            i++;
            swap(list, i, j);
        }
    }

    swap(list, list[i + 1], list[hi]);
    return (i + 1);
}

private void swap(int[] list, int a, int b){
    if (a >= list.length || b >= list.length){
        return;
    }

    int temp = list[a];
    list[a] = list[b];
    list[b] = temp;
}

private int getPivot(int[] list, int li, int hi){
    int mi = hi / 2;

    int chosen = Math.max(Math.max(list[hi], list[li]), list[mi]);

    System.out.println(chosen);
    return chosen;
}
}
```

Comment: in what way is it not working correctly?

Comment: Your `partition` method seems off.  Normally I see two loops there.  One to move an "upper" partition down and one loop to move a "lower" partition up.

Comment: I'll toot my own horn a little here, but if you want some commentary on a quicksort implementation you can compare comments here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/226467/quicksort-with-insertion-sort-and-improved-pivot-selection

Comment: @ACarter The array isn't being fully sorted. Some numbers are, usually on the left side, but there are a few oddball numbers that are out of place. Here's a comparison of one of the outputs:

Before
[9, 3, 1, 7, 2, 18, 4, 49, 94, 23, 11, 71]

After
[1, 3, 7, 2, 49, 9, 18, 4, 23, 11, 94, 71]

Comment: It's `partition` that does the actual sorting.  So for example, `if (list[j] < pivot){ i++; swap(list, i, j);` At no point do you check that the value at index `i` is greater than `pivot`, so there's some "oddball" values for you right there.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing wrong parameters to method `swap()` when swapping the pivot at the end of `partition()`.

Change

```
swap(list, list[i + 1], list[hi]);
```

to

```
swap(list, i + 1, hi);
```

Additionally the following check in method `swap()`:

```
if (a >= list.length || b >= list.length){
    return;
}
```

should not be needed. Values of `a` and `b` could be too high only due to the above mentioned mistake but with correct code it should never happen.